# apply discriminator only while deserializing in mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, discriminator

Can I apply discriminator only while deserializing? I just want to ignore discriminator while writing document back to MongoDB. Possible?

Comment: post some relevant code ...

Comment: I don't have relevant code yet but based on certain Parent class property value I want to discriminate. I could achieve that but it is causing issue while saving document.